# What's the reference, generic function, germ of an analytic function in Hilbert's theorem about representability by composition of fewer variables?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

**What is Hilbert's reference, a generic function and a germ of an analytic function in Hilbert's theorems below?**

[Khovanskii, A.: Topological approach to 13th Hilbert problem. Department of Mathematics, University of Toronto, February 19, 2019, page 4:](https://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=15609&pcode=HIL2019)
"Theorem 3 (D.Hilbert)
*Generic analytic function of $n$ variables can not be represented as a composition of analytic functions of fewer than $n$ variables.*"

Khovanskii, A.: Topological Galois Theory. Solvability and Unsolvability of Equations in Finite Terms. Springer, 2014, p. 289:
"Theorem D.5 *There exists a germ of an analytic function of $n$ variables that is not representable as a composition of analytic functions of fewer than $n$ variables.*"

It seems there are many meanings of the mathematical terms "generic" and "germ", and their definitions aren't given in many texts.

I have not found these quotes anywhere else.

I'm not familiar with topology.

related: [Approximating a function by another with fewer variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729713/approximating-a-function-by-another-with-fewer-variables)